# Current TimeZoneOffSet from webservice by passing city or airportcode

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

I was looking for web service which gives me `timeZoneOffSet` by passing `city code` or `airport code`. Kindly help me

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Writing code is not big thing for me but timezone change for each country at certain period of year. Which some webservice can give me accuratly

Answer (score 0):

You can get timezone offset if you provide timezone of place.

```
kk = new Date() ;
kk = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"});
kk.getTimezoneOffset();'
```

will return you timezoneoffset

Comment: Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone/15171030#15171030

Comment: Thank you for reply. I was looking for webservice, as reason is now London time zone is 0 and after march it will be +1. So my question is will I get accurate zone whenever it changes. @user3279680

Comment: have a look at Google Time Zone API. It may help you